Units digit of 2024th term in $x_{n+1} = 4x_n + \lfloor\sqrt{11}x_n\rfloor$ with $x_1=1$
The sequence is given by
$x_{n+1} = 4x_n+\lfloor\sqrt{11}x_n\rfloor$
Or
$x_{n+1} = \lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})x_n\rfloor$
and $x_1=1$.
I coded for the first 12 terms and suspect the units digit is periodic with period 4. But I do not know how to prove this. If it is indeed periodic it is trivial to find the $2024^{th}$ digit.

Hint:  show that the sequence satisfies a linear recursion with integer coefficients.

Not much thought or effort shown I must say. Please take a [tour] of what counts as a good question on MSE.

@lulu Thanks a lot ,I am able to solve it now ,can you share your motivation for this approach

$4+\sqrt {11}$ is quadratic and it's conjugate, $4-\sqrt {11}$ is very small so it seems reasonable to look for a quadratic relation... terms involving powers of the small root become meaningless and are removed by the floor.  Didn't have to work,  but it seemed likely.

I suggest: post your solution below.  That way users here can check your work and the cite can consider the question resolved

Here is some python code to check the first n terms, set the number that n must be less than to the amount of iterations you want:                                                                               import math
x = 1
n = 1
while n < 2024:
print(x)
x = math.floor((4+math.sqrt(11))*x)
n += 1

@MrChessR the growth of $x_n$ is exponential so python will give precision error

It is easy to calculate that $x_{1} = 1$ , $x_{2}=7$  .
$x_{n+1} = 4x_n+\lfloor\sqrt{11}x_n\rfloor$
$ \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 8x_n-4x_n+\lfloor\sqrt{11}x_n\rfloor$
$ \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 8x_n+\lfloor-4x_n+\sqrt{11}x_n\rfloor$
$ \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 8x_n-\lfloor4x_n-\sqrt{11}x_n+1\rfloor$
$ \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 8x_n-\lfloor(4-\sqrt{11})x_n+1\rfloor$
$ \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 8x_n-\lfloor(4-\sqrt{11})\lfloor (4+\sqrt{11})x_{n-1}\rfloor+1\rfloor$
Now $(4+\sqrt{11})x_{n-1} -1  \le \lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})x_{n-1}\rfloor \le (4+\sqrt{11})x_{n-1}$
Multiplying the inequality by $(4-\sqrt{11})$ it easy to see that
$\lfloor(4-\sqrt{11})\lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})x_{n-1}\rfloor\rfloor= 5x_{n-1} -1$
$ \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 8x_n-5x_{n-1}$
Now it easy to see that the unit digits follow the pattern $1,7,1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7 ...$ so unit digit of $x_{2024}$ is 3.

Did you mean $9, 7$ where you typed $7,9$?

Also, something is wrong with $(4-\sqrt{11})\lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})x_{n-1}\rfloor= 5x_{n-1} -1$ since the right side is an integer and the left side is not

@J.W.Tanner They prolly forgot the floor on the left.

Are you familiar with the theory of linear recurrence relations? If yes, it might be easier to start off with $y_{n+1} = 8y_n - 5y_{n-1}, y_1 = 1, y_2 = 7$, and then show that $y_n = x_n$ by induction.

@J.W.Tanner thank you for pointing out the mistakes ,I have corrected them now

I do appreciate your posting this as an answer as I had no idea how to do this. +1 I think I'd fill in a couple more details on how can conclude as you did:
"Multiplying the inequality by $(4-\sqrt{11})$ it easy to see that
$\lfloor(4-\sqrt{11})\lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})x_{n-1}\rfloor\rfloor= 5x_{n-1} -1$' As this question/answer is for everyone who is interested in this, not just the person asking.
